# is there some way to more efficiently package/assemble code than using sbt assembly?

Tags: java, performance, scala, sbt, packaging

I'm using `sbt assembly` at work to package jar files to test or deploy.  The tail of the output:

```
[info] Checking every *.class/*.jar file's SHA-1.
[info] SHA-1: 93cd61b71cc796dbff699be75e034c7b731ed1bb
[info] Packaging /home/...../target/scala-2.10/pricing-etl.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 2725 s, completed Apr 4, 2014 10:49:32 AM
```

2725/60 = 45 minutes.  This isn't a large project, and the computer I'm using is quite powerful.

Is there a way to turn off the SHA-1 hashes (which seem to take a large portion of the time)?  Is there some more efficient alternative plugin?

**UPDATE**:  I'm not claiming SHA-1 specifically is slow, only that I know the computer sits there with the last output being "[info] Checking every *.class/*.jar file's SHA-1" for a good number of minutes. I'm just looking for solutions, regardless of the cause.
Maybe I need a faster hard drive?  Maybe not doing the SHA-1's would save time, regardless of if the slowness is caused by IO issues?  I'm currently trying to do some development, and locally need to be able to test changes.  I can't wait 45 minutes between tests, and since I'm not yet deploying a fix to production I'm not overly concerned about verifying the correctness of the hashes.

Comment: Maybe. But before I looked into that, I would understand the risks. SHA-1 is a cryptographically secure hashing mechanism, and this step is to ensure that the files are correct and complete ... skipping it runs the risk of having software that does not work.

Comment: It would be nice to know how many .class files and how many megabytes the occupy in total, 'cause those times seem outrageous and SHA1 calculation should not take anywhere near that long. I just did a GB of SHA1 over 193,000 .class files and it only took 28 seconds. Admittedly, I iterated 83 times over 2,324 files that in total occupy 12M (meaning only 12 M of I/O to the SSD in my laptop occurred), but I still cannot see how it could take SBT-Assembly that long to do the SHA1 calculations. I repeated this for my Mac's /Library directory tree, which holds 3.1 GB in 29,158 files. It took 52 sec.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be SHA-1, unless your project has many Gibabytes. On some historical HW it did [150 MB/s](http://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html). Check the CPU usage, usually nearly everything is IO bound.